# PHP Auth User/Pw Return null if set in URL?

Tags: php, http-auth

I am trying to validate HTTP basic auth using PHP. I read https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

When I try to validate PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW I noticed something odd. If I include the credentials in the url such as user:password@(domain) those are null but done normally they are set as expected. Is there any way to validate in PHP auth credentials in the URL like this?